# Java - How does relative folder creation differ from non-compiled code to an executable

Tags: java

I am making a Java program that I will wrap to become an .exe for testing and production. Part of the programs initialization process is to make a folder named "config" on the same level as the executable file. For illustration:

```
---> Parent Folder
       ---> myProgram.exe
       ---> config/
```

That is what ideally what should happen.

As of now, I'm testing this block of code:

```
String config_dir = "./config";

if(!new File(config_dir).exists()){
    new File(config_dir).mkdirs();
    return;
}
```

And what it does is to check if the directory exists, and create it if it doesn't.

However, this code is run by my `Main.java` class, and when it goes one level higher to create the `config` directory, it is still on the same level as the other folders *inside* the workspace directory:

```
---> MyProject
       ---> bin
       ---> external_lib
       ---> src
       ---> config
```

Which makes sense since I only made the app create the folder one level higher. However, after it is packaged as an exe file, it needs to make that folder on the same level as the exe file. I am just worried that it might not work that way.

Does anyone have a way to ensure that a folder is created on the same level as the packaged executable Java file? I'm working on a Mac and it might take time to be able to test it.

Comment: Since you speak of ".exe" files, I assume this is supposed to run on Windows. In that case, it might be wiser to create your data files in the `%APPDATA%` directory instead, as programs are more-or-less supposed to do. That also means that the user won't lose their config files if they move the executable around.

Comment: @Dolda2000 is this `%APPDATA% directory visible or easily reachable by the user? The config file might need to be updated from time to time.

Comment: I don't often use Windows, so I don't remember exactly how it looks like, but I think the real name is "Application Data" or somesuch, and is normally located in your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

From a "running a JAR" perspective, you could use

`System.getProperty("user.dir")`

which returns the path where the JVM was started from. Once you turn this into an executable, I'm unsure exactly what you might need. But you might also try

`getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`

Comment: Remember that [getCodeSource() can return null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource--).

Comment: @VGR that's a true statement. Thanks.

Comment: @Gregg It will only do that if you run from an exploded directory of .class files. If you run from a JAR file, it won't. `System.getProperty*"user.dir")` is pretty pointless, as you can just use `.`.

Answer (score 0):

> Java

Irrelevant.

> How does relative folder creation differ from non-compiled code to an executable?

It doesn't.

> I am making a Java Program that I will wrap to become an .exe for testing and production. Part of the programs initialization process is to make a folder named "config" on the same level as the executable file.

For that purpose you need to *know* the location of the executable file. For a C or C++ executable that is given by `argv[0]` of the `main()` method. For Java JAR files it is given by `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`.

```
String config_dir = "./config";
```

That will create a folder in the *current working directory of the user*, same as returned by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. Not 'at the same level as the executable file'.

> However, this code is run by my Main.java class, and when it goes one level higher to create the config directory, it is still on the same level as the other folders inside the workspace directory:

It is still in the current working directory. Your workspace has nothing to do with it unless it is the current working directory.

> However, after it is packaged as an exe file, it needs to make that folder on the same level as the exe file.

No. In the current working directory. Always. That's what `.` means.

> Does anyone have a way to ensure that a folder is created on the same level as the packaged executable java file?

See above, but, judging by comments and what you've accepted in your own answer, I don't think that's what you actually want. I think you want it in the current working directory, and that's what you're getting. What the current working directory actually *is* depends on how you run the program, and where from. If you run from within the IDE you will get the IDE's idea of it. If you run from a command line you will get the shell's `cwd`. If you run by double-clicking you will get whatever `cwd` is defined for the double-click, which *may* be the directory of the executable or JAR file.